# Why can't I constrain a concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

It's not allowed to constrain a concept like this:

```
template<typename T>
concept A = expr_1;

template<A T>
concept B = expr_2;   // error
```

However, it seems the same result can always be achieved like this:

```
template<typename T>
concept A = expr_1;

template<typename T>
concept B = A<T> && expr_2;   // ok
```

What's the reason for not allowing the first version, if it can always be rewritten as the second?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a feature-design standpoint, a user should not have to look in multiple places to find the same information.

A `concept` defines a series of constraints on its template parameters. Those constraints are listed after the `=` sign; that's the point of them. So a user should be able to see everything about a concept by finding the `=` sign and looking at the expression following it.

Your way means that I would have to look in up to three places: the constraints on the template parameter definitions, the `requires` clause of the template header (which would have to be possible now, because that's how constrained parameters are defined to work), and the expression following the `=` sign.

Why bother with that increased complexity, when you can just spell it out properly? Code is read more often than it is written, so we should bias towards simpler reading rather than convenient writing.

From the perspective of how the feature is defined, a `concept` is just a `constexpr static bool` variable with some special functionality attached. That's why it uses an `=` sign to define its value.

To constrain a template means that this template definition *does not exist* if the constraint is violated.

So given `template<A T> concept B`, what is the value of `B` when `A<T>` is `false`? According to normal C++ template constraint rules, it doesn't have one. Indeed, the variable doesn't even *exist* if you try to instantiate it with such a type.

So it's not the same meaning at all.