# What is the rationale to disallow type traits in type-constraints in addition to concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, language-design, c++-concepts

The language specification, when introducing Concepts, implicitly disallows type traits [to be used](https://godbolt.org/z/4986cz849) in type-constraint contexts in lieu of concepts:

```
#include <type_traits>

// doesn't work because std::is_arithmetic_v is not a type
template <std::is_arithmetic_v T> struct A{};

// legal, but doesn't restrict T, but expects an object of type std:: is_arithmetic
template <std::is_arithmetic T> struct B{};
```

I vaguely remember that during the specification process, people where unable to get the concept of Concepts to work without introducing a new `concept` keyword and the corresponding mechanism for defining a Concept.

However, in the definition of `A`, the construct `template <bool-expression ID>` was never legal, so allowing it would not have clashed with other language constructs.

So, what stands in the way of directly allowing such constructs instead of having to [introduce a lot of wrapper-Concepts for already existing std type traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts) — not to mention custom type traits?

---

Note: It is clear that writing a generic `concept` template to wrap existing type traits is trivial. It is not the question *how* to reuse old traits, but why the language didn't opt to allow it in the first place? Perhaps even *instead of* introducing a new keyword.

Comment: I chose `std::is_arithmetic` as a specific example, because C++20 neglected to introduce a corresponding `std::arithmetic` Concept.

Comment: That is a good question, I also always wanted to write `template <concept C> concept a = ...` as well. But "concepts" are not "bools".

Comment: @TheMoisrex Not sure what that means, but be aware that `concept` definitions cannot be constrained by other concepts. Why that is sensible is a wholly different question, I think.

Comment: @TheMoisrex: "*I also always wanted to write `template <concept C> concept a =` ... as well.*" Why should the reader of your code have to [look in *two places* to figure out what your concept is constrained on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61293390/why-cant-i-constrain-a-concept/61293531#61293531)?

Comment: Variable templates don't even have a type.

Comment: @T.C. Templates never have a type, but their instantiation does. So `std::is_arithmetic_v<T>` has type `bool`. For all intents and purposes it is equivalent to the expansion of a concept template.

Comment: @bitmask: "*For all intents and purposes it is equivalent to the expansion of a concept template.*" Except that a concept is *always* a boolean. The compiler doesn't have to instantiate a template to find out if the text is legal. There's no way to know the type of a variable template until you instantiate it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Interesting. Is that the reason? Sounds a bit like the start of an answer.

Comment: @bitmask: You didn't ask what the reason might be; you asked what the reason *is*. I can only speculate, since I wasn't there when the decision was made.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, looking two places to figure out the constraints is not the best, but what I meant by that example was the ability to pass a concept as a template parameter, it can solve creating a temporary classes like `template <typename T> struct is_a { static constexpr bool value = some_concept; }` just to carry a "concept" around.

Comment: @TheMoisrex: Passing around a concept is not a thing you should *want* to do. And certainly not through a boolean expression; that loses *all* of the power of concepts.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's not that I want, it's that I need to pass around constraints around. Yes, passing it through bools loses the power of it, but that's only because we can't pass it around normally. Just imagine Lazy Evaluation; passing around concepts can play a good part in those situations, and that's just one reason why passing concepts is a nice feature to have.

Comment: @TheMoisrex: "*It's not that I want, it's that I need to pass around constraints around.*" And I'm saying that whatever you're doing that *creates* that need is probably a bad design. "*Just imagine Lazy Evaluation; passing around concepts can play a good part in those situations*" Um... why? What concept are you passing around? Are you trying to make a generic lazy evaluation system that can be used for *any* lazy evaluation, where the user writes a concept that then is used to generate the actual lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 2):

The ordinary evaluation semantics of type traits denies defining any meaningful **relationships** among them; lacking that *subsumption* would prevent many productive uses of constrained declarations.  For example:

```
template<nonstd::is_semiregular_v T> void f(T);
template<nonstd::is_regular_v T> void f(T);
void g(int i) {
  f(i);  // error: ambiguous
}
```

The corresponding code with concepts selects the overload with the **stronger** concept (which might have better semantics or be more efficient).

Comment: I see. But this is an argument for concepts being introduced in the form of `concept`, but it doesn't really preclude *also* allowing variable-template type-traits for non-overlapping constraints. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @bitmask: If you make it easy for people to bypass `concept`s, then they will *bypass `concept`s*. And they will lose all of those features. Discouraging people from using the wrong tool is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

The very first paper defining what would eventually become the C++20 concepts feature [was N3580 (PDF)](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) from early 2013.

In N3580, constraints are defined to be any `constexpr` template function that takes no function parameters and returns a `bool`. However, the `concept` keyword does exist and does have a justification for existing. In particular, the keyword is what opens up the use of constraints in specialized syntactic constructs. Section 6.2.3 lays out the reasoning:

> It seems that we need two names for every concept: one for the concept/constraint itself plus one for its constrained parameter name. [...] Our solution is that the name of a constraint doubles as the name of its constrained parameter. This then implies that a constraint that is to be used for the terse syntax must be syntactically distinguished. In other words, it must be defined to be a concept using a special syntax or a keyword. We use `concept`.

This is stated within a section discussing terse syntax for constraining templates. Things like `template<ConceptName T>`.

So it is clear that the very genesis of `concept` *as a keyword* was to allow for using concept names in specialized syntax.

Obviously the concepts functionality evolved substantially over time. In particular, the dual-name issue became irrelevant as using a concept-name to represent the typename deduced from it disappeared entirely. But in every version of "concepts-lite", the keyword `concept` represented the separation between "a boolean expression I can use in a constraint" and "a special entity that can be used in particular grammar".

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't follow. What is this business about two separate names? And why is the *'separation between "a boolean expression I can use in a constraint" and "a special entity that can be used in particular grammar"'* necessary?

Comment: @bitmask: The document goes into more explicit details about the issue as it appeared in that version.